# How to locate Key in Windows Registry?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe5

I am trying to get the BIOS version from the Windows Registry using Delphi. My problem is that the subkey path is not the same for all Windows versions.

Windows 10 : `Reg.OpenKey('\HARDWARE\DESCRIPTION\SYSTEM\BIOS',False)`

Windows 7 : `Reg.OpenKey('\HARDWARE\DESCRIPTION\SYSTEM',False)`

Is there a way to locate the BIOS version whatever the path to it actually is?

Comment: Sounds like your approach is wrong. Why not use WMI?

Comment: i will look into it.

Comment: Look at the [Win32_BIOS wmi class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394077.aspx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting with Windows Vista you can use the [`Win32_BIOS`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394077(v=vs.85).aspx) WMI class to get the BIOS version. Try this sample code.

```
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

uses
  System.SysUtils,
  Winapi.ActiveX,
  System.Win.ComObj,
  System.Variants;



procedure  GetWin32_BIOSInfo;
const
  WbemUser            ='';
  WbemPassword        ='';
  WbemComputer        ='localhost';
  wbemFlagForwardOnly = $00000020;
var
  FSWbemLocator : OLEVariant;
  FWMIService   : OLEVariant;
  FWbemObjectSet: OLEVariant;
  FWbemObject   : OLEVariant;
  oEnum         : IEnumvariant;
  iValue        : LongWord;
begin;
  FSWbemLocator := CreateOleObject('WbemScripting.SWbemLocator');
  FWMIService   := FSWbemLocator.ConnectServer(WbemComputer, 'root\CIMV2', WbemUser, WbemPassword);
  FWbemObjectSet:= FWMIService.ExecQuery('SELECT * FROM Win32_BIOS','WQL',wbemFlagForwardOnly);
  oEnum         := IUnknown(FWbemObjectSet._NewEnum) as IEnumVariant;
  while oEnum.Next(1, FWbemObject, iValue) = 0 do
  begin
    Writeln(Format('SerialNumber         %s',[String(FWbemObject.SerialNumber)]));
    Writeln(Format('SMBIOSBIOSVersion    %s',[String(FWbemObject.SMBIOSBIOSVersion)]));
    Writeln(Format('Version              %s',[String(FWbemObject.Version)]));

    Writeln('');
    FWbemObject:=Unassigned;
  end;
end;


begin
 try
    CoInitialize(nil);
    try
      GetWin32_BIOSInfo;
    finally
      CoUninitialize;
    end;
 except
    on E:EOleException do
        Writeln(Format('EOleException %s %x', [E.Message,E.ErrorCode]));
    on E:Exception do
        Writeln(E.Classname, ':', E.Message);
 end;
 Writeln('Press Enter to exit');
 Readln;
end.
```